Misaligned column view
I get a misaligned column view in the following example.
This is test.org:
#+COLUMNS: %5TODO(ToDo) %30ITEM(Task)

* AAA
* TODO BBB

and this test.el:
(find-file "test.org")
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil :height 0.7)
(org-columns)

Now I start emacs with emacs -Q -l test.el. As you can see the columns are misaligned due to the modified height attribute of org-todo face.
I tried to customize the :height attribute of org-column face, but it didn't work.
Any idea how to reset the :height attribute in column view?

You can advise the functions org-columns and org-columns-quit: add a :before advice to org-columns to reset the height to 1.0; add an :after advice to org-columns-quit to set the height back to 0.7:
(find-file "test.org")
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil :height 0.7)

(defun my/reset-org-todo-height (&rest _x)
  (set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil :height 1.0))

(advice-add 'org-columns :before #'my/reset-org-todo-height)

(defun my/set-org-todo-height (&rest _x)
  (set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil :height 0.7))

(advice-add 'org-columns-quit :after #'my/set-org-todo-height)

(org-columns)


Thank you. That does work. -- Changing the face on a global scope is quite intrusive, but anyway much better than before.

Well. it's a globally defined face and it is used by font-lock, so there is not much choice here.
